# can't save file in VS 2015

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

I have visual studio 2015 ultimate version.
Now I have a problem that i can't save files.
I try to save the specific file(ctrl + s or any other save operation) and instead of saving the file, the VS arise a save dialog popup:
[image]
Nevertheless if i try to save i get the following error:
[image]

This situation influence only part of my code.. I can't understand why this exactly happen.
Any suggestions?

Update:
I closed the vs and tried to delete the projcet.
This is the output window i got**(I have windows 10)**:

[image]

Comment: Backup content of those files (if not other way, then by copy-paste). Then you can try whether you can modify them in another editor, e.g. Notepad. This will help you better understand the problem.

Comment: It is a low-level Windows error, ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS.  You'd expect somebody to carefully document what specific directory he's trying to save to, what the attributes on the existing file look like and how it interacts with source control.  But we only have pictures to look at.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have the same problem regularly happening to me. Requires a reboot of Windows 10 in my case - very frustrating.